# Android RRO - overlay custom attribute

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

In my main Android application, I have defined an attribute and it points to some color. It looks something like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="ThemeColors">
    <attr name="my_button_background" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And then I have my syle

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="my_button_background">@color/color_blue</item>
</style>
```

After that, i setup my button like this:

```
<Button
    style="@style/some_style"
    android:text="@string/some_text"
    android:background="?attr/my_button_background"/>
```

Now, **in my overlay app**, if I do something like this, and it works perfectly

```
<color name="color_blue">#FFFF00</color>
```

But, if I want to override attribute using this, it does not work.

```
<color name="my_button_background">#FFFF00</color>
```

Alternate solution is to wrap `color_blue` with something like `color_button_background`, then use that as a pointer for my attribute, and override that in my RRO. But it just brings up a lot of clutter. And I have tons of attributes, which will make this job much more time consuming.

Can someone please help me with this one? Is there a way to overlay attributes? I tried Googling this one out, but I found no solution.